# How to fetch required fields from namedtuple based on condition inside a loop and save it to a JSON file in python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

How to fetch required fields from namedtuple based on condition inside a loop and save it to a JSON file in python.

I have 2 namedtuple as below. Now inside the loop i am only interested in feching K/V pairs based on "if" condition.

Currently I am filtering those fields and can see the result by print(k, v), but not able to save those K/V pairs in Json file as Json structure. The University is fetching all fields from Student and College namedtuple but I am only interested in College Namedtuple, so put a filter as "if" condition.

Tried with json module with json.loads or json.load with "append". Please suggest.

```
Student = namedtuple("Student",
              ["Summary", "Certificates"])
College = namedtuple("College",
              ["id", "age", "marks", "ranks"])

def to_json_file(university):
    for k, v in zip(college._fields, college):
       if k in {"id", "age", "marks", "ranks"}:
         print(k, v)
```

Edit (1) :-

Iteration Output :

```
Id 143
age 17
marks 459
ranks 27th

Id 139
age 17
marks 398
ranks 48th
...
...
```

Only I need to save the k,v generated from the print statement in a json file without overwrite the file.

Edit (2) :-

```
Sample :

<class '__main__.College>
College(id='143’, age=’17’, marks=’459’, ranks=’27th’)
College(id='139’, age=’17’, marks=’398’, ranks=’48th’)

<class '__main__.Student’>
Student(Summary=’pass’, certificates=’issued’)
Student(Summary=’pass’, certificates=’issued’)
```

Comment: Assuming `college` is based on the `College` named tuple, there is no need for your `if` statement. Perhaps you should include some sample data with your expected result.

Comment: Only I need to save the k,v generated from the print statement in a json file without overwrite the file.

Comment: Please provide a sample of `university` and `college`.

Comment: see my edit(2). Is this what you wanted ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without understanding the structure of your data (e.g. `college` and `university`), this question is hard to answer.  I am surmising that `college` is a list of named tuples.

```
import json

def to_json_file(college):
    result = []
    for c in college:
        result.append({k: c[n] for n, k in enumerate(c._fields)})
        # Or for cpython 3.6+: result.append(dict(c._asdict()))
    return json.dumps(result)

college = [College(143, 17, 459, '27th'), College(139, 17, 398, '48th')]
>>> to_json_file(college)
'[{"id": 143, "age": 17, "marks": 459, "ranks": "27th"}, {"id": 139, "age": 17, "marks": 398, "ranks": "48th"}]'
```